# Question about installing NVIDIA driver: "You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported"

Tags: gpu, nvidia, tesla

I appreciate your time looking at this issue.

I’m not sure if this is the Tesla K80’s issue itself or there are other things that I can try. Current, I’ve had the GPU Tesla K80 inserted. However it shows “You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported” when I performed “sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.104.run.” or “NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.80.02.run”.

It was previously fine on the other computer, and some day, when I typed "nvidia-smi’, then this Tesla K80 was not detected (No any information about K80). Before this, the computer has even complained about no connection to Tesla K80 and suggest a reboot when typing “nvidia-smi”.

When I took out the Tesla K80 to another computer, I could feel it is quite warm even if no one is using it (quite strange…). Then, this Tesla K80 was inserted to another computer without NVIDIA Driver installed. So I want to install the driver to see if I can see Tesla K80, but I failed to install the driver.

I hope if anyone could give some advices for me to try? Thank you inadvance!
Below is the log file that I performed “sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.104.run”.

nvidia-installer command line:
./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 48 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 32.
-> Tagging shared libraries with chcon -t textrel_shlib_t.
WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 410.104 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system. For further details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in the README available on the Linux driver download page at [www.nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com).
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 410.104.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC=“gcc32”.
ERROR: Unable to determine the version of the kernel sources located in ‘/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64/source’. Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the ‘kernel-source’ or ‘kernel-devel’ RPM installed. If you know the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the ‘–kernel-source-path’ command line option.
ERROR: Installation has failed. Please see the file ‘/var/log/nvidia-installer.log’ for details. You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at [www.nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com).

====================
when I typed "pkg -l | grep -i nvidia": nothing shown
"lspci | grep -i nvidia": nothing shown
'dmesg | grep -i "nvidia"' :
[ 6662.403250] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 6662.403264] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[ 6662.539651] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 6662.673347] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[ 6662.674050] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 6662.674345] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
[ 6762.248535] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[ 6762.249108] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 6762.249255] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
[ 6813.106747] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[ 6813.107254] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 6813.107395] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[ 6993.285291] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[ 6993.285711] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 6993.285850] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[ 7467.419202] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[ 7467.419650] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7467.419788] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[ 7478.210409] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[ 7478.210816] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7478.210934] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[ 7819.845969] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[ 7819.846405] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7819.846528] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[ 7839.007094] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[ 7839.007689] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7839.007856] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
[13150.989882] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[13150.990303] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[13150.990454] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 239